# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope

Tags: angularjs

Estou obtendo o seguinte erro ao rodar o meu teste:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope

LoginController.js

```
(function(){
'use strict'; 

angular.module("app")
    .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

LoginController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$controller', 'EntryPointService', 'initResolver'];

function LoginController($scope, $rootScope, $controller, EntryPointService, initResolver){
    $controller('BaseController', { $scope: $scope });

    var initialize = function(logged, stateName) {
        if(logged && stateName === 'login') {
            $scope.$state.go('master.modules');
        } 

        if ($scope.$state.is('logout')) {
            $scope.showLogoutPopup();
        }
    };

    initialize($rootScope.operator_logged, $scope.$state.$current.name);

    if([null, undefined].indexOf(initResolver) !== -1){
        $scope.$state.go('init');
    }

    $scope.STCPAppVer = $scope.StcpUtilsService.getAppVersionToView();
```

LoginController.Spec

```
   describe('LoginController test suite', function(){    
   beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));                             

   var $scope, controller, state, base, rootScope, httpBackend, scope;

   var fakeRequest = function(){
       return;
  }; 

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $state, 
  $httpBackend, $scope){      
      state = {};
      state.go = sinon.stub();
      state.$current = {};
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      $scope.showLogoutPopup = sinon.stub();
      $scope.$state = state;
      $scope.$state.is = function(val){ return $scope.$state.$current.name === val; };
       rootScope = $rootScope;
      $scope.showLogoutPopup = sinon.stub();
      base = $controller('LoginController', { $scope: $scope, $state: state 
});
      controller = $controller;
      httpBackend = $httpBackend;
      scope = $scope;

  }));

    it('function LoginController', function(){

  });
```

O que está faltando? Porquê está ocorrendo este erro?

Comment: Esse é todo o código que você tem?

Comment: acho q essa sua declaração do $scope está dando conflito.    var $scope. Terceira linha do LoginController.Spec

Comment: Como o CCastro disse, deve ser essa sua variavel que esta dando erro no scope, tente tirar o $scope do inject e mudar o nome da variável para outro

Comment: Ao retirar o $scope como indicado apareceu o seguinte erro: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: initResolverProvider <- initResolver <- LoginController @CCastro

Comment: @LINQ não, só mandei uma parte.

Comment: Ao retirar o $scope como indicado apareceu o seguinte erro: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: initResolverProvider <- initResolver <- LoginController @JulioBorges

Comment: O que é esse initResolver? algo q vc escreveu? Caso positivo, ele, q deve ser um initResolver.js, tem q ser incluso lá no seu index.html

Comment: CCastro ele já está incluso mas o erro persiste

Comment: Vc retirou o $scope do inject? caso positivo, retorne ele novamente ao inject, mas não declare no var.

Comment: @CCastro as dicas foram seguidas porém nada mudou

Comment: Se quiser subir o código para algum git eu dou uma olhada.